# How to bend a sci-fi corridor BUT maintain the straight panels?

Tags: modeling

Howdie, guys and gals! Okay so I've been using 3DS Max for about 19 years now but I moved over to blender about a month ago. I've settled into it rather well and can use it with great speed now so it's all good there. Really liking Blender so far! However I am wanting to, for personal development only, create some sci-fi corridors. I had intended to create them in a sort of modular format so that I could simply model one section, UVW unwrap it and then copy it multiple times. Below is the model that I had been working on. However I'd like to be able to bend multiple copies around whatever arc I'd like to.

I thought that maybe it wasn't working because of the arched ceiling panels but, as seen in the second picture, they have something similar and are able to do it. When I do it I just get big gaps between the two models.

I've been trying to figure out the best way to do it for days and I just can't figure it out. I've tried using a bend modifier and an array with a curve. They somewhat work but the panels get heavily distorted and/or curved. I need to be able to keep the panels, etc. straight.

Do you think it's because of the drastic angles that I have going on? I originally thought that may be the problem but, as seen in the third image, it shouldn't be an issue...

Any ideas?

[image: Example 01.]

[image: Example 02][image: Example of the type of corridor I am trying to make.]

Comment: I have encountered a similar problem, but the funny thing is you actually answered my question in yours.

Comment: Reading further into the question, the version where you actually have the panels unbent but they have gaps sounds like it’s the end of the line. You would have to make the panels be able to stretch along their own tunnel axis without stretching in any other way.

Comment: I've thought about, and tried stretching them out but then I still have that weird gap at the top that can't be fixed with stretching it. Only other thing I can think of would be to taper the panels. So confusing lol.

Comment: I don’t quite understand what you mean by the funny gap at the top. In the first image, a tiny portion of a very large gap all the way along the panel joint is highlighted.

Comment: Yes I highlighted that to show the gap. The curved triangular shape. It joins fine at the top but then it curves outwards as it goes further down.

Comment: This seems rather simple. Because in that system the second panel is not getting deformed at all, and apparently it’s point of rotation is in line with the top joint, the bottom part which is farther away from what would be the center of the tunnel wil of course swing out and no longer be connected. If the panels have perfectly straight up-and-down edges wherever they join… Ha ha! That might be a solution.

Comment: I’m not sure how you can do the ceiling, though. You may have to use two or three arrays to do this. however, there is one more option. Try making all the panels out of edges that goes straight from one end to the other without breaking in any way, unless they are at the end going straight up and down.

Comment: Use modifiers to add detail to the mesh after the deformation.

Comment: Hmmm I suppose I could model the panels as one long piece and then just bend them then add the dividers. Only problem is somehow getting the additional detail perfectly rotated and aligned the the panels once they've been curved. Your idea is actually pretty good to be honest but adding the finer details to each panel, afterwards, could be tricky.. Unless I can somehow make them on a plane and them snap the plane to the face of the panel but it's a start I guess?

Answer (score 3):

I was finally able to work out how to do it... Basically I only bent the major forms and made sure to use as few vertical edges as possible. For the little insets, things that NEED vertical edges, I used a simple object - copied a few times, joined to and then bent with the main panels. After that, using the "Normal" transform orientation and making notes of scale values, etc. I was able to then work along the faces at their respective angles.

It's a repetitive process but I can think of no other way of doing it without causing deformations.

In a way I suppose it's better to work like this as it means I can save out exact measurements and scaling values, etc. for the other modular pieces so that things remain uniform.

Of course I'll continue to look for an easier way of doing this - maybe align perfectly to centre of a face somehow? I had originally had a plane going around as well, to snap the other parts to but it didn't seem to work properly.

For now this will do!

[[image: First example][1]]